# Влияние кол-ва запросов в транзакции на производительность

Tags: sql, база-данных, транзакции

Нужно ли отправлять изменения в БД одной транзакцией, или каждый INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE лучше выполнять отдельной транзакцией? Что лучше при выполнении 10 несвязанных запросов (не нужно откатывать предыдущий запрос при ошибке последующего), отправить их одной транзакцией, или каждый по отдельности? Какой вариант лучше для производительности приложения и субд?

Comment: Смотря какая производительность имеется ввиду. Если надо что бы быстрее завершилась сессия которая производит эти изменения - то одна транзакция на все гораздо эффективнее. Если же интересует время отклика других сессий во время изменений - то это уже другой разговор и зависит он от того какая БД используется

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В общем случае ни первый ни второй вариант не являются оптимальными с точки зрения производительности.

Если нужно удалить(вставить/поменять) действительно большое количество строк, в первом случае мы получаем большие расходы на открытие, закрытие большого количества транзакций.

Во втором случае имеем слишком огромную транзакцию, которая тоже под конец работы будет долго закрываться, да ещё и рискуем упасть, т.к. размеры транзакции ограничены(видел такую ошибку всего на нескольких миллионах строк).

Как-то писал скрипт удаления "ненужных" данных. Сталкивался с обеими проблемами.
Скрипт запускался на выходных, и удалял несколько десятков миллионов строк. Т.е. проблемы блокировок и прочего не волновали, в приоритете была скорость.
Чтобы наглядно продемонстрировать, написал небольшой скрипт. `MS SQL Server`.

Кратко что он делает:

- `T_TABLE` - таблица с данными
- `T_RESULT` - таблица с результатами эксперимента
- `P_INSERT_ROWS` `@Count` - вставляет в таблицу `T_TABLE` `@Count`
  строк
- `P_DALATE_ROWS` `@Count`, `@Pack` - удаляет из таблицы `T_TABLE` все строки в транзакциях по `@Pack` штук, и записывает затраченное время в таблицу `T_RESULT`.

Финальный скрипт запускает в цикле вставку 1 000 000 строк, и их удаления пачками по 1, 10 .. 1 000 000 штук.
И затем выводит содержимое `T_RESULT`.

Скрипт:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('P_INSERT_ROWS', 'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC P_INSERT_ROWS;
IF OBJECT_ID('P_DELETE_ROWS', 'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC P_DELETE_ROWS;
IF OBJECT_ID('T_TABLE', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE T_TABLE;
IF OBJECT_ID('T_RESULT', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE T_RESULT;
GO
CREATE TABLE T_TABLE (
  id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  Number INT,
  String NVARCHAR(4000)
)
CREATE INDEX IN_T_TABLE_NUMBER ON T_TABLE(Number ASC)
CREATE TABLE T_RESULT (
  execute_time DATETIME,
  Cnt INT,
  Pack INT
)
GO
CREATE PROC P_INSERT_ROWS 
  @Count INT 
AS
;WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT N+1 FROM CTE WHERE N<@Count
)
INSERT T_TABLE
SELECT N, LEFT(REPLICATE(N, 100),4000)
FROM CTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
GO
CREATE PROC P_DELETE_ROWS 
  @Count INT,
  @Pack INT
AS
DECLARE @TTT DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @NumberStart INT = 1
WHILE @NumberStart < @Count
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN;
    DELETE FROM T_TABLE WHERE Number BETWEEN @NumberStart AND @NumberStart + @Pack - 1 OPTION(RECOMPILE);
  COMMIT TRAN;
  SET @NumberStart += @Pack;
END;
INSERT T_RESULT
SELECT GETDATE()-@TTT execute_time, @Count Cnt, @Pack Pack
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE 
  @Count INT = 1000000,
  @Pack INT = 1
WHILE @Pack <= @Count
BEGIN
  EXEC P_INSERT_ROWS @Count
  EXEC P_DELETE_ROWS @Count, @Pack
  SET @Pack *= 10;
END
SELECT * FROM T_RESULT
GO
```

Содержимое `T_RESULT`:

```
execute_time    Cnt Pack
1900-01-01 00:15:05.183 1000000 1
1900-01-01 00:01:56.003 1000000 10
1900-01-01 00:00:32.200 1000000 100
1900-01-01 00:00:22.370 1000000 1000
1900-01-01 00:00:21.940 1000000 10000
1900-01-01 00:00:22.663 1000000 100000
1900-01-01 00:01:10.327 1000000 1000000
```

Как видим, лучший результат по времени выполнения имеем, когда удаляется в одной транзакции пачками по 10000 штук, т.е. это намного эффективнее, чем удалять по одной записи в транзакции, и эффективнее, чем удалить все строки в одной транзакции.
Эксперимент не строгий, запуски влияют друг на друга, но всё равно показательно.

**UPD**: Добавлю, что на практике, транзакции в реальной жизни не часто бывают большими. Кроме запросов вида DELETE FROM T, пожалуй.:) В этом случае да, чаще всего если есть возможность обернуть несколько действий в одну транзакцию - лучше обернуть.

Answer (score 4):

Я полагаю, что такая постановка вопроса изначально неверна. Транзакция по сути своей это атомарная операция с точки зрения бизнес-логики, а не с точки зрения БД. Именно так.

Простейший классический пример с дебетом и кредитом счетов. Дебет и кредит разных счетов **должны** производиться в пределах одной транзакции, безотносительно вопросов к производительности. То есть списание денег с одного счета и зачисление той же суммы на другой счет - это одна транзакция (одна атомарная операция с точки зрения бизнес-логики). Если мы начнем эту атомарность разбивать на 2 операции апеллируя к производительности - это путь в никуда и приведет к нарушению целостности данных (как в примере с дебетом/кредитом: при падении системы, деньги с одного счета спишутся, а на другой не зачислятся).

Посему, я бы считал, что границы транзакций должны определяться бизнес-логикой приложения, но никак не исходя из других соображений.

Другой вопрос, что если логика позволяет границы транзакций проводить и так и эдак, то совершенно очевидно, что чем короче транзакция, тем она более производительна. Механизм реализации транзакций предполагает в классическом варианте, блокировку таблиц на уровне записей затрагиваемых транзакцией. Чем длиннее транзакция - тем больше записей блокируется. Чем больше записей блокируется, тем ниже производительность.

Answer (score 0):

самый главный скажу что надо каждый раз отдельно открывать транзакцию потому что транзакция определена 1 атомарная операция.
Если ты будешь использовать за нескольких изменение за 1 транзакцию то у тебя будет в базе проблемы.

1. может создаться 'Dead Lock' ситуация.
2. нагрузка будет при открытом состоянии транзакция.
3. кто соединяется в этот базу и исполняет какие-то изменения , изменение остается неподтвержденной. а это что означает будет проблема не сохраненная информация. Потому что когда ты будешь это подтверждать мы не знаем.

я хочу отметить еще один момент транзакция определена одному реальному атомарные операцию.это может состоять много операций за одним атомарным процессом. (можно использовать ' Insert' и 'Update' одном (атомарном) транзакция Ну это уже твой операция то есть что ты делаешь в предметной области).

Если будет мини-проект и только ты будешь этом использоваться тогда нет проблемы. Думать о дальнейшем!

Comment: Не согласен. если надо быстро провести те изменения которые требуется, то одна транзакция на все гораздо эффективнее. говорить о возможных dead lock не зная какая именно СУБД используется бесполезно. при открытом состоянии транзакции у того кто меняет нагрузка не велика. так что из всего ответа соглашусь только с одним утверждением: у других пользователей (транзакций) увеличится время ответа потому как во первых они могут попасть на блокировку, во вторых СУБД может принимать меры, что бы показать данные как они были до начала открытой транзакции, что так же отнимает время

Comment: @Mike - нет, это он сам, из головы: "самый главный первый я"

Comment: @Mike когда пользователи будет взаимодействовать с одним таблицам может создаться 'Dead Lock' ситуация.

Comment: @Mike базы пользователя не взаимодействует напрямую они действуют от другого программы думаешь что есть соединение миллион а когда открыто остаётся транзакция у него открывается нити задачи вот если не будет большой объём пользователей тогда нет проблем если много то тогда есть проблема

Comment: @Igor Тебе надо книгу читать я скажу только тебя автор .) itzik ben-gan.

Comment: @RasulHuseynov Если правильно подходить к проектированию таких транзакций и соблюдать порядок апдейта таблиц то dead lock вполне можно избежать. А если порядок не соблюдать, то и на коротких транзакциях можно запросто deal lock устроить. А будут отдельные нити на транзакцию или нет, зависит от СУБД и от режима подключений. например Oracle держит нить на коннект, вне зависимости от того есть на ней открытая транзакция или нет.

Comment: @Mike я с тобой так согласен если это проект очень маленький это возможно а если большой это невозможно

Comment: @Mike То есть если это маленький Да не будет проблемы нагрузки не будет проблемы 'Dead Lock' .ну в большой объем информации базе это невозможно

Comment: @Mike Я просто перечислил проблемы которые я видел и читал.

Comment: @RasulHuseynov Ну объем базы тут не причем. можно и на 10Tb базу держать и выполнять изредка такие транзакции и все будет ok. А можно сделать пару таблиц с парой записей и на них устроить и dead lock и все что хочешь, особенно если у БД блокировки на уровне страниц, как у Sybase (и подозреваю, что по наследству и у MSSQL). Вопрос скорее в интенсивности и видах нагрузки. для OLAP большие транзакции обычно допустимы, для OLTP систем они недопустимы.

Comment: @Mike Я не говорю большой объем базы данных просто. много взаимодействующих пользователей. самое главное проблема. в OLTP Да недопустимо.